# Run function on Login Success MGTwitterEngine ala FBConnect

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working with the engine for the first time and am fairly new to iOS development. I' m curious though if there's a way to call a function after I log in successfully? I can't seem to get it to work along the lines that FBConnect called for fbDidLogin after your initial login function. I have MGTwitterEngineDelegate declared and I tried to use the following code after login:

```
//TWITTER LOGIN FUNCTION/////////////////////
-(void)twitLogin{
    NSLog(@"Inside of twitLogin...");
    if(![_engine isAuthorized]){  
        UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];  

        if (controller){  
            [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES]; 
            NSLog(@"Inside of Twitter login UIWebView.");
        }  else {
            NSLog(@"ONCE WE'RE LOGGED IN, LETS SEND THE TWEET!");
            NSString *tweet = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"My Tweet!"];
            [_engine sendUpdate:tweet];
            NSLog(@"You just tweeted: %@",tweet);
        }

    }  else {
        NSString *twitterToken=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"authData"];
        NSLog(@"Twitter is authorized?: %@",twitterToken);
        //Twitter Integration Code Goes Here
        NSString *tweet = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"My Tweet!"];
        [_engine sendUpdate:tweet];
        NSLog(@"You just tweeted: %@",tweet);
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I posted previously didn't work %100,  turned out I didn't have the right delegate set for login success in my controller:

```
#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterController Delegate

- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSLog(@"Authenticated with user %@", username);

    tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self updateStream:nil];
}
```

Hope that helps anyone!